# Create Parquet file out of array

Tags: java, arrays, database, file, parquet

I am currently struggling with creating a parquet file from an Array of a self created class. I am Using java 1.8.

I can't figure where i should start. Already searched at StackOverflow and Google but there is no answer that fits to my case.

I have an array of Orders which have  customerID, orderID and  list of OrderItems.
OrderItems have informations like articleID, amount etc.

Can some one give me a quick introduction on how to convert this array into a parquet database file?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of your code so that someone could reproduce and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet:

```
private void generateParquetFile(List<Order> orders){
    //Parse the schema
    Schema schema = parseSchema();
    List<GenericData.Record> recordList = getRecords(schema, orders);
    writeToParquet(recordList,schema);
}

private static void writeToParquet(List<GenericData.Record> recordList, Schema schema) {
    // Path to Parquet file in HDFS
    Path path = new Path("/Users/example/dev/TestRecord.parquet");
    ParquetWriter<GenericData.Record> writer = null;
    // Creating ParquetWriter using builder
    try {
        writer = AvroParquetWriter.
                <GenericData.Record>builder(path)
                .withRowGroupSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE)
                .withPageSize(ParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)
                .withSchema(schema)
                .withConf(new Configuration())
                .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)
                .withValidation(false)
                .withDictionaryEncoding(false)
                .build();

        for (GenericData.Record record : recordList) {
            writer.write(record);
        }

    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        if(writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private List<GenericData.Record> getRecords(Schema schema, List<Order> orders) {
    List<GenericData.Record> recordList = new ArrayList<GenericData.Record>();
    GenericData.Record record = new GenericData.Record(schema);

    for (Order order : orders){
        record.put("CustomerNumber", order.getCustomerNumber());
        record.put("OrderNumber", order.getOrderNumber());

        Schema childSchema = record.getSchema().getField("Artikel").schema().getElementType();
        List<GenericRecord> artikelliste = new ArrayList<>();
        GenericRecord artikel = new GenericData.Record(childSchema);

        for(OrderItem item : order.getOrderItems()){
            artikel.put("ArticleNumber", item.getArticleId());
            artikel.put("Amount", item.getAmount());
            artikelliste.add(artikel);

        }

        record.put("Article", artikelliste);

        recordList.add(record);
    }

    return recordList;
}

private static Schema parseSchema(){
    Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema schema = null;
    try {
        //pass path to schema
        schema = parser.parse(new FileInputStream(new File("/Users/example/Documents/avroSchema.avsc")));
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return schema;
}
```

This is working form, at least a *.parquet file is generated.

I am not sure how to check if the parquet file is generated like i want to.
Also i am not sure if its already compressed with snappy? Because I am giving a CompressionCodec of type Snappy to the ParquetWriter.

Maybe someone did something like this already and can help me?

Comment: Hello, Could you also please share the import statements? I'm facing issues with trying to write to parquet in java as well